# Using Windows.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider; in the Windows Phone 8.1 or the Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I cannot find the library `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in the namespace `Windows.Security.Cryptography`, in Windows Phone 8.1 or the universal app and store app.

Answer (score 4):

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` is part of the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace which is not available in Windows Runtime apps. You should use `AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider` class from `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core` namespace.

```
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmKeyProvider provider=AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("<algorithm-name>");
```

The `<algorithm-name>` parameter can be any one of the values from `AsymmetricAlgorithmNames` enumeration. There are multiple variants of RSA. 
                                                                           http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.asymmetricalgorithmnames.aspx

Comment: Thanks Sridhar for your answer ... but i need to use the RSA algorithm or AES Encryption algorithm

Comment: Just use autocomple on Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core by typing `Names`